# Excel formula or VBA required to resolve this case complicated

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Dear Team Could you please help me on below case

In the excel file we have name and department with available resources

First table we have details and second table need to fill with number or just comments YES or NO.

I have tried with IF formula it will not be helpful because cells keep moving based on second table which changes daily

Formula which I have tried no useful

```
If(A2&b1=a12&b11,if(b2<0,"No","Yes"),"Match not found")
```

Could you please help me. VBA am new no idea how this case can be helpful

[image]

Comment: Do both tables in discussion look like you show us? I mean, they contain the same number of rows and the same sorting? Can you elaborate a little, from this point of view? Then, will the first table contain unique names and the second one not? Should these tables exist in two different worksheets?

Comment: Sorry i was away correct two different sheet and first table rows and columns will be fixed but in second table only few column and row details will be there as per requirements

Comment: Then, try the code I supplied. It processes your actual situation (from the picture you show), but it would be easy to adapt it to process in two sheets. Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to transform the first table from the cross-table layout to tabular (aka unpivot):

e.g. 1st column=name, 2nd column=department
then add 3rd column as combo: “name/department” (or any other delimiter in between)

| a1 | 1011 | a1/1011 | 1 |

| a1 | 1033 | a1/1033 | 3 |

etc.

In the second crosstable you could use vlookup/xlookup:

match criteria is the respective combo of the name to the left and the department on the column header (e.g. A12&”/“&”B11)

Match (vlookup) this against 3rd column from first table (in tabular layout) to get back then value (or “yes”) - this should work dynamically based on the value in the respective column and row headers (and not dependent on the position of the cells)

Use PowerQuery to unpivot and add 3rd column and replace the numbers with “yes” to create tabular version of first table

Comment: Sorry this table will be huge first and second table for example have shown in short table to understand the case .... Transform option not useful here because of many column and rows .... Second table department data will be keep changing

Comment: My understanding is that by changing of table 2 that the names and departments are always in different order. 
If you use the combo to create the match criteria, it does matter.   
If you look up for e.g.  a1/1033 is does not matter where a1 and 1033 is located in the 2nd table.  Also, you can still keep first table as cross-table. When you change something there, the PowerQuery can update the tabular accordingly (can be stored in a desperate/hidden sheet)

Comment: Correct match criteria in power query? .... honestly till now I never tried and used power query

Comment: PowerQuery only to create the tabular version of first table as reference: https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/

Comment: Xlookup inside 2nd table e.g. from B12:D17 as cell function

Comment: In B12 the match  criteria is A12&”/“&B11 etc.  Then it does not matter what it the actual value in A12 and B11, as it will pick always the “correct” value.   Then xlookup against tabular table

Comment: Thank you atleast i found the way how to reach solution with new learning ..... Am trying to find solutions in xlookup formula..... I will try now tabular and xlookup both

Comment: Another way is to use use INDEX & XMATCH in second table  to find the matching row index and column index in first table to get the value from that coordinate … (this might be easier than PowerQuery as it only Involves cell function）

Comment: I just found this: example 3 is basically your use case    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312

Comment: Did you check the link? You can do it with just cell function. Example 3 illustrates your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a clarification question, but you were not interested in answering it.

Anyhow, I prepared an answer which should be fast enough, using arrays and a dictionary. It uses the ranges you show us in the picture. I wanted to configure it for using two sheets and automatically calculating the last row of each.

It assumes that in the first table there are unique names. In the second one may be as many names as you want, in any sorting order.

Please, test the next code and send some feedback:

```
Sub matchNames()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, dict As Object
  Dim rngGlob As Range, rngRow As Range, arrGlob, arrSrc, i As Long, j As Long, arrYes, arrRet
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = 7 ' if can be calculated, if two sheets will be used: sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  Set rngGlob = sh.Range("A1:G" & lastR): arrGlob = rngGlob.Value2
  
  arrSrc = sh.Range("B11:D11").Value2 'the array of numbers to be matched in the global array
  arrRet = sh.Range("A12:D17").Value2 'the array of the range to return (Yes...)
  
  
  'place the "Yes" string where the numbers exist in an array and load the dictinary:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 2 To UBound(arrGlob)
     On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no any value on the processed row:
        Set rngRow = rngGlob.rows(i).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, rngGlob.Columns.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
     On Error GoTo 0
     If Not rngRow Is Nothing Then arrYes = getYes(rngGlob, rngRow, arrSrc)
        
     dict(arrGlob(i, 1)) = IIf(IsArray(arrYes), arrYes, vbNullString)  'place the array containing Yes as Item
     Erase arrYes
  Next i
  'place the dictionary arrays value in the array to be returned:
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrRet)
       arrYes = dict(arrRet(i, 1))
       If UBound(arrYes) = UBound(arrSrc, 2) - 1 Then
             For j = 0 To UBound(arrYes)
                  arrRet(i, j + 2) = arrYes(j)
            Next j
        Else
            'place empty strings, to clean eventually older values whchid does not correspond, anymore
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrSrc, 2) - 1: arrRet(i, j + 2) = "": Next j
        End If
  Next i
 
  sh.Range("A12").Resize(UBound(arrRet), UBound(arrRet, 2)).Value2 = arrRet
End Sub

Function getYes(rngGlob As Range, rng As Range, arr) As Variant 'it returns the "Yes" array per name
     Dim rngH As Range, arrY, i As Long, cel As Range, mtch
     ReDim arrY(UBound(arr, 2) - 1)
     Set rngH = rng.Offset(-(rng.row - 1))
     For Each cel In rngH.cells
        mtch = Application.match(cel.value, arr, 0)
        If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
            arrY(mtch - 1) = "Yes"
        End If
     Next cel
    
     getYes = arrY
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the codes....  Results not showing anything table 1 we can keep in sheet1 and table 2 which we need to keep in sheet 2 .... Results showing nothing

Comment: In same sheet also tried not showing results

Comment: If we keep two sheets also good to me .... As of now results not coming anything

Comment: @Does the code run, not raise any error and do nothing in the second table?  Is this what I should understand from your comments? I tested the code and it works as it should on my workbook... Now, are the used numbers to be matched formatted the same in both locations? If you have TheamViewer of AnyDesk installed on your computer I can connect and tell you what problem you have... And not working in two sheets is the same with not working on only once. Two sheets version should come only after seeing this working.

Comment: No error in code it is not displaying results in cells... Sorry i do not have theamviewer ... Shall I give my gmail id

Comment: @Rahul2020  What can we do with that gmail ID? I wanted to show you what problem you have and how to debug such a code. With your assistance and showing the data to be processed. I do not want to start deducing what you try doing...

Comment: If you are at home, you can install one of the two applications in less then 3 minutes... TeamViewer is preferable, but AnyDesk will also work convenient if we settle that each of us will move the mouse cursor when it is its turn...

Comment: @Rahul2020 Did you, at least, checked if the used ranges (set according to what I could see in your picture) are exactly in the same position in the workbook you try the code? Can you share the workbook (using my personal mail form my profile, or a transfer site) if no remote connection is possible?